# What motivation does an omnipotent god have to do anything?

Tags: metaphysics, theology, happiness

For example, every human action is motivated by happiness. So what reason does god have, to do or create things? happiness can't be the only reason, because he can make himself infinitely happy without having to do so.

Comment: God is also omnibenevolent, and his omnipotence is constrained by that side of his nature. His omnibenevolent nature dictates what he values and acts upon, so he does not do all that he can do.

Comment: As you say, "motivation" is a concept that applies to human actions. Maybe it does not apply to gods...

Comment: The very inaction of god can have results, eg, he can simply allow things to happen. God can be both omnipotent and indifferent. Or, he can care at some point and then stop. This is [deism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deism).

Comment: Boredom? Loneliness?

Comment: a) Happiness is not the final motivation, see Maslow. b) You state that God _does or creates things_, that's quite a subjective assumption, which implies multiple other assumptions, so it is you that should answer that.

Comment: What makes you think, even if an omnipotent god exists and has motivation, that you'd be able to comprehend them? Very opinion-based.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Please be aware that questions are subject to editing and closure, and that reflects the site's policies on acceptable questions and NOT a personal attack. [What to avoid in questions](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Questions, including those that are closed, can be edited to bring them within guidelines. [Keeping questions on-topic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Additional clarification at [the meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Welcome, cheeser12

Merely as omnipotent (having infinite power) God has no motivation to do anything. Only if you introduce other attributes, the most obvious being omnibenevolence (having infinite goodness) and join them to omnipotence do you have anything that God might will to occur and have a motive for bringing about.

It seems not too much to say that if God is omnipotent and omnibenevolent, then God necessarily wills, and is motivated to bring about, all the goodness God's omnipotence enables God to bring about.  Anything less, and God is not omnibenevolent.

Two points on your question and this answer. One: it is not entirely clear what omnipotence covers and includes. Descartes extended God's omnipotence beyond the logically possible - i.e. God is not bound by logical possibility. God can do the logically impossible. Few share this view of omnipotence but the nature of God's omnipotence (assuming that there is a God and that God is omnipotent) is a subject of contestation. 'God can do everything that can be done' - but what is the precise sense of 'can be done'?

Two: I follow Aquinas in holding that God's nature - God's essence - is simple (if there is a God, as he did not doubt but others do). It cannot properly be specified by enumerating separate attributes such as omnipotence, omniscience, and omnibenevolence. We are constrained by the limitations of finite intellect to conceive of God in this kind of 'discursive', departmentalised way but really God has a simple, indivisible essence which cannot be represented as a compound of attributes.

'But you concentrate purely on the Judaeo-Christian God'. True, but if a different God is assumed the substance of my answer still holds. Qua merely omnipotent being God can have no motives. Only if you add extra attributes such as omnibenevolence, or even (if you like) limited benevolence as John Stuart Mill hypothesised in his idea of a God who merely 'pays some regard, to the happiness of his creatures, but who seems to have other motives of action which he cares more for' and abandon the Judaeo-Christian God - *only then* can God be motivated to bring anything about. I might add that to ascribe motivation to God is in my view yet another product of the limitations of finite intellect: we conceive of God as a person and we think of persons as having or lacking motives. My own view is that God, if there is a God, is not a person (certainly not on the model of ourselves) but only analogous to a person. Our thinking about the divine analogises God as a person because (as it seems to many) we have no better way of conceiving God.

Comment: Very balanced treatment of a question that is worthy of discussion although outside the bounds of proof. Cheers,

Comment: Charles M Saunders - thank you for this comment, which I value all the more because of the extra quality your questions and answers have brought to PSE. Best - Geoffrey

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether motives, purposes, goals, aspirations, ambitions, desires, intentions, etc. are co-reducible enough or not, the question of divine willpower can be answered in enough ways for us to speak allegorically about a divine impulse as such at some juncture in our terms.

But let's examine the contrast example of human actions being universally motivated in terms of happiness. Since happiness is not pleasure (alone), but is an emotion, and one that constellates over emotions in total as the emotional state of achieving goals/purposes/intentions (vs. sadness, its opposite formally), it is true but not substantive to say that all human actions are motivated by happiness. It's almost as if to say that we're motivated by motivation to be more motivated, which might make for a clever joke about inspirational posters or "live, laugh, love" decorations, but will not clearly contrast us as such with a divine nature. For at most we only say that God being miraculously euphoric forever is the *same thing as* God being all-effective, ultimately.

God would know Its own efficiency, and Its knowledge is Its will (according to some), so that God would still be able to act for the sake of being infinitely happy, in one act comprised by infinite numbers of subactions that could include creations of worlds and transformations of souls and whatever. That is, for all we know, the very means God uses to "become" absolutely happy are the subactions we attribute to God anyway.

Comment: As with the answer above, your response is extremely well thought through and expressed in a very balanced philosophical exposition. You made no reference to any type of belief system, one way or the other, Thank you.